# Is there a spread operator for golang structs

Tags: go, struct, embed, operator-keyword, spread

Have the following structs where `PostInput` is a param for a `createPost` function.

```golang
type PostInput struct {
  Title String
  Content String
}

type PostInputWithTime struct {
 Title String
 Content String
 CreatedAt Time
 UpdatedAt Time
}
```

But do not want `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` to be exposed to users so i add it inside the function like so.

```golang
func createPost(input PostInput) {
  updatedInput = PostInputWithTime{
    Title: input.Title
    Content: input.Content
    CreatedAt: time.Now()
    UpdatedAt: time.Now()
  }
  db.InsertOne(updatedInput)
}
```

It is working fine but curious if there is a more elegant way to do it? I know it's possible to embed struct on another struct but not on the root layer (like javascript spread operator).

```
// something like this
type PostInputWithTime struct {
 ...PostInput
 CreatedAt
 UpdatedAt
}
```

Comment: No, there is no spread operator for structs in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a spread operator for go[...] structs [...] like javascript spread operator [?]

No.

(You either have to use embedding, copy the values or implement some reflect-based magic, but no, no spread.)

Answer (score 0):

```
type PostInput struct {
  Title string
  Content string
}

type PostInputWithTime struct {
 PostInput //Struct Embedding
 CreatedAt time.Time
 UpdatedAt time.Time
}
```